# How to Model data using UML for this situation?

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, uml, software-design

The Situtation is that there is a data named `Progress` which has 2 valid values (suppose `'A'` and `B`). this means `Progress = 'A'` or `Progress = B`.  `A` is just a `string`, but `B` is `not string`. `B` itself has some valid values (suppose strings: `'V1'`, `'V2'`, `'V3'`). `progress` can be `A` which is a `string` or can be `B` which is `'V1'`, `'V2'` or `'V3'`. How to model this data?

[image]

If `B` is just a simple string (just like `A`) so we can define `Progress` as a `string` but i think one solution is defining `progress` as a class which has two children: `Class A` & `Class B`. `Class B` has 2 fields: `Id & state` so we have 3 IDs which correspond to 3 `states`: `'V1'`, `'V2'` and `'V3'` and `Class A` with a `const` field called `state` with  fixed value `'A'`. so with this solution `progress` can be objects `A` or `B` which has a `state`.

Please help me if such design is not good or if there is any design pattern for such situation.

Comment: `a data named Progress` : no, *Progress* is a variable, a data is a value. `Progress = B ... but B is not string` : you do not assign *Progress* with *B* but with its value, and that value is a string so in all cases you assign *Progress* with a string (supposing the single quote defines a literal string rather than just a character as in C(++)). The rest of your question seems to indicate you confuse class and instance of class

Comment: @bruno - how do you model the image?

Comment: to model it I need first to know what your image represents, is the possible value *Progress* can have after the assignment ? what *Progress* is ?

Comment: in my system progress is the progress of constructing a structure. i want to know the state that the structure is in. the state can be value: 'A', 'V1', 'V2' or 'V3'. but  state 'A' is logically separated from  'V1', 'V2' or 'V3'. they are logically 2 different types of  progresses.

Comment: `constructing a structure` : do you mean *assigning* / *initializing*? else are you at a meta level ? sorry but I do not understand you, you need to edit your question to make it clear

Comment: Looks just like a nested enum. Why not just have `A`, `V1`.. `V3` as valid entries? The last three would be that `B` state. I think you're thinking too much about it.

Comment: @qwerty_so Are there nested enums in UML?  I thought that we would be bound to a list of enum literals.

Comment: @Christophe Actually you are right. I was talking out of a programming experience where language designers found that too limiting and made enums more of a 1st class citicen. To make it UMLish you probably need two different enums here. Besides, there is no string in an enum, but only `EnumerationLiteral`s.

Comment: @qwerty_so Indeed,  there are a couple of nice language innovations that are not (yet?) in UML, such as swift’s enums with associated values or c++ enum classes which make enum (almost) first class citizens

Comment: @Christophe Hehe. Swift is where I got that from. (Not that I like the language too much at all.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since I'm not 100% sure if you speak about classes in a typed language or objects in a dynamically typed language, I'd like to clarify the obvious:  UML uses typed objects.  So [object](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html#object-diagram) instances such as `progress` must be of a class `Progress` that defines their properties and behaviors.

If your question would really be only about data and values, since there is no overlap between `'A'` and `'Vn'`, the easiest way would be to define `Progress` as a class with a sole property that is of type `String`.

But from your narrative, I understand that it's not just about data but also about semantics and potentially object behaviors:

- One way to address your requirement is to use class specialisation: `Progress` would have a generalization set with two specializations, `ProgressString` (with a sole `String` property) and  `B`  (with itself having a string property).  Moreover the generalization set would have the constraint [`{complete, disjoint}`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html#is-covering)
- Another way is to use [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) (caution do not confuse object composition with UML composition): `Progress` would have two properties, a `String` and a `B` (defined as above).  If you'd give them a multiplicity of `0..1` you could use a constraint to make sure that it's either the one or the other but not the two.

In both cases, if you want the string to be limited to the possible values that you have documented,  you'd need to add a constraint.  Alternatively,  you could go for a more expressive model, using an [`«enumeration»`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/data-type.html#enumeration) to make explicit the  possible values (as qwerty_so suggested in the comments).